# Opera won't stay logged into facebook page after restarting browser?

Tags: windows-7, opera, facebook

Using Opera 31.0.1889.174 on Windows 7 64-bit.  If I log into a facebook "page" (not my main facebook) and then close the browser and re-open it and visit facebook it will no longer be logged into my facebook page but instead to my main facebook.

By contrast Google Chrome and Firefox will maintain the login to the facebook page between restarts.  Why does this happen and is there a way to change Opera so it will stay logged into a facebook page between restarts?

Comment: This works fine for other people, so my guess would be that you've got some particular privacy settings (cookies?) that are preventing you from staying logged in.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter: does this work for you personally where opera stays logged into a facebook fan page?  How do you know it works for others? To be clear it keeps me logged into facebook just not the specific facebook fan page. I do not believe I have made any custom privacy tweaks